# Recommended Android app

Tags: classification, resources, recommendations

Do you recommend any specific Android app to keep track of the different beers (and of course different kind of beers) that you have tasted?

Someone recommended me Untappd but I may need something less social and more informative...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Beeradvocate.com](http://www.beeradvocate.com/app/)

[Beer Expert - from "Rate Beer" data](http://www.thebeerexpert.com/beer-expert-app.shtml)

Both of these are the largest rating/tasting databases for beer, I haven't used them but they would be the place to look for the information that untapped is lacking.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of an Android app, I personally use [Beer Citizen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.definitionstudio.beercitizen&hl=en). It does not have every beer imaginable in its listing, but it has quite a large amount. I find the community to be pretty helpful. They helped me find a lot of different beers whenever and wherever I might travel.

Jeff Wurz is also right to suggest Beer Advocate, which recently came out with a new app back in June of this year. I do frequently use Beer Advocate's website and am eager to try out their new app. If you end up not liking Beer Citizen I would recommend trying this app out; though I base this off the usefulness of the website, since I have no experience with the application.

Hope I was able to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

I like [Untappd](https://untappd.com/). It would be better if it automatically recognized the beer labels, but it is fine. You must type the beer name.

Comment: he explicitly said Untappd isn't what he wants.