# Apps for recording variety of beers consumed

Tags: taste, varieties

I'm looking for apps, as a beer aficionado, to record the different beers that I try. Is there a [vivino](http://www.vivino.com/app/) for beer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended Android app](http://beer.stackexchange.com/questions/939/recommended-android-app)

Comment: @user1126 - Could you clarify the platform? If Android, I'd like to close this question as a duplicate of the aforementioned. (A closed question does not affect or harm your reputation in any way.)

Comment: Untappd works well for me. I can see all the beers I have tried and what I rated them. I also use BeerMe (Windows Phone)

Comment: Related: https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/q/2139/43

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest the app [Untappd](https://untappd.com). It gives you an opportunity to comment on beers and include pictures and locations. You can even earn badges that notate various "beer achievements".

Comment: Is that Untappd?

Comment: Yes, it is Untappd. Unlike Vivino, you have to type the beer name.

Comment: Not just the name, you can also search the for the brewery, as well as adding your own (generally small batch colabs). It's a great app

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion most of such apps are not what you really need and they often lack something. Therefore I simply use Google Drive Spreadsheet. As cheap as it sounds, it has everything that you want out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used Pintley on iOS (but it's cross platform) and found it to be a pretty good app.  The quality of the graphics isn't intensely refined, but the beer list is very comprehensive.  I found that the beer list was one of the most important things in an app like this, since I was usually in quick situations when I wanted to record and rate a beer.  I didn't want to be out with friends and browsing through a ton of pages to finally have to input all the details of a beer that was fairly common.

A friend of mine just switched to Beer Citizen (also cross platform), which seems to have a more refined look.  I've done some searching through the database though, and there seems to be quite a bit missing...

Answer (score 1):

Beer Buddy. Hands down best beer tracking, rating, and review app ever. It's associated with ratebeer.com so if you have an account with them you can sync your reviews.